# Downloaded DBpedia data does not include all instance-types triples

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

I downloaded some data from http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2015-04/core/,
including: [`instance-type_en.nt`](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2015-04/core/instance-type_en.nt), [`mappingbased-properties_en.nt`](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2015-04/core/mappingbased-properties_en.nt), and some others.

I have successfully loaded them into [OpenLink Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) DB, but when I run some sample SPARQL query, e.g., a query to see all the triples about a subject `Xiamen_University`, the problem appears.

```
select ?s  ?p  ?o
where 
  {
    ?s  rdfs:label  "Xiamen University"@en  . 
    ?s  ?p  ?o  .
  }
```

From the DBPedia SPARQL endpoint, there are [heaps of triples](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fs%20%20%3Fp%20%20%3Fo%0D%0Awhere%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%22Xiamen%20University%22%40en%20%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20%20%3Fp%20%20%3Fo%20%20.%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) about `iamen_University`; while in my db, there are only 4 or 5 of them.

Especially, there is no triple in db indicating `Xiamen_University` is a type of University, or any instance-type triples at all. I found similar cases on some other subjects as well.

I think the `instance-types_en.nt` file does not include all the `instance-types` triple from Wikipedia, same problem with `mappingbased-properties`. Is that right? If so, where could I find the right source file?

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole list of the datasets available at on the [downloads page](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads2015-10#datasets).  I don't see lots of documentation about *exactly* what's in each one of them, but the names are fairly descriptive, and the question mark links next to each one show a preview of what kind of information is in each one of them.  Hovering over each title will provide a short description.  E.g.:

[image: screenshot of tooltip]

It looks like to get most of the interesting properties, you'd probably want the **mappingbased** datasets, along with the **labels** dataset (since the query that you wrote identifies objects by label).

Comment: As @Joshua said, mapping-based is what later on is in the `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` namespace. But the most data is not mapping-based and belongs to the `http://dbpedia.org/property/` namespace. Especially what's contained in the files whose name starts with "infobox properties".